# Net framework 4.8 install failed: Cannot find object or property

Tags: .net, .net-4.8

I've tried to install Net Framework 4.8 but the installation returned

*Install did not succeed, Cannot find object or property*

I've tried many solutions, Like using the Net framework repair tool,  Offline installer, etc.

None of them work, so I've decided to check the cbs.log and that's what I got:

```
Wait for Item (x64-Windows10.0-KB4486153-x64.cab) to be available
x64-Windows10.0-KB4486153-x64.cab is now available to install
Creating new Performer for Exe item
Created new ExePerformer for Exe item
Action: Performing Action on Exe at C:\5a9f17874cff9e1d385125\x64-Windows10.0-KB4486153-x64.cab
Launching CreateProcess with command line = dism.exe /quiet /norestart /online /add-package /packagepath:"C:\5a9f17874cff9e1d385125\x64-Windows10.0-KB4486153-x64.cab"
Exe log file(s) :
C:\Windows\logs\cbs\CBS.log
Log File C:\Windows\logs\cbs\CBS.log exists and will be added to the Watson upload list
Exe (C:\5a9f17874cff9e1d385125\x64-Windows10.0-KB4486153-x64.cab) failed with 0x80092004 - Cannot find object or property. .
Exe Log File: CBS.log
PerformOperation on exe returned exit code 2148081668 (translates to HRESULT = 0x80092004)
Action complete
Error 0x80092004 is mapped to Custom Error:
OnFailureBehavior for this item is to Rollback.
Action: Performing actions on all Items
Restart manager will not be used since the current operation is not install.
Action complete
Action complete
Final Result: Installation failed with error code: (0x80092004), "Cannot find object or property. " (Elapsed time: 0 00:02:46).
```

Then I've checked the registry and it seems like net48 is already installed in a registry POV

registry value of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\Release shows 528049.

However my program does not detect it so it asks me to install the net framework, and it seems like the installer does not detect it as well, How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I have fixed this issue by reinstalling fresh new OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you land on this topic by its title like I did I hope this helps.
I was getting this error on a build server while trying to install/update .Net Framework 4.8 using TeamCity CI ... MSBuild was throwing this error
"*Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1175, 5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.8 were not found.*"
And when I installed 4.8 developer pack I would receive "*Cannot find object or property*".. this was due to .net runtime 4.8 already existing which would prevent the rest of the developer pack from installing. Most forums say uninstall VS and reinstall the latest version.. which seemed a bit of an over reaction.

To get around this I found the [**Build Tools for Visual Studio 2022**](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/?q=build+tools)
This updates the necessary build tools and allowed msbuild to compile without error.

Comment: You need to scroll down on the page, direct link is https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/?q=build+tools#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2022